# Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to engage module : rampart

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, soap, apache-axis

Do you have any knowledge on setting up Axis2 and Rampart for a SOAP **client** application ?

I've added both Axis2's and Rampart's jar files to the build path via Eclipse and coped Rampart's jars and mar file to Axis's file structure.

I'm doing something wrong with Axis/Rampart setup but I'm clueless to what…

This is all the log gives me to go on:

com.good.gc10.Fault: Can't instantiate GCServiceStub
at com.good.gcTalk.GCSoapClient.(GCSoapClient.java:51)
at com.good.gcTalk.GCTActivationPinHandler.main(GCTActivationPinHandler.java:34)
**Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to engage module : rampart**
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.engageModule(ServiceClient.java:363)
at com.good.gcTalk.GCSoapClient.(GCSoapClient.java:45)

Comment: were to able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your Config Context?

This needs to be set before you can engage Rampart, You also need to have the folder structure correct.
ie In the below example you would need to have the following subfolder in Axis2WithRampart:
Conf,
Resources,
Modules

If you add log4j with the Rampart & Axis 2 settings you get more information logged.
I can tell you how to do this if you're not sure.

```
enter configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("Axis2WithRampart/repository", null); 
//create the stub
stub = new MyRampartServiceStub(configContext,"http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/MyRampartService"); here
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error, Can you show me more detail about how to load rampart module ? I am using eclipse.